# How to print pages in mix mode portrait & landscape

Tags: html, angular, printing, landscape, portrait

I have an angular component which is used for UI rendering and printing. I am using window.print command for the same. I need initial 2 pages in landscape mode and after page break,1 page in portrait mode.

I have tried to set orientation as landscape/portrait in corresponding div and also text-rotation solution. But nothing worked. Any other way to achieve the same? Thanks in advance.

Comment: in a single document you can only have one orientation. either print it in phases or have landscape for all pages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried CSS property `page` ?
This property is used to specify a particular type of named page.

> Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/#propdef-page

As the CSS below, you can add the `landscape-page` or the `portrait-page` class to the element you mean to display in landscape or portrait mode.

```css
@page orientation-portrait {
    size: portrait;
}

@page orientation-landscape {
    size: landscape;
}

.landscape-page {
    page: orientation-landscape;
}

.portrait-page {
    page: orientation-portrait;
}
```

Unfortunately, this property works well in Google Chrome but not Firefox and Safari...

Comment: Anyone experienced issues with this in Chrome? When printing to pdf, I'm getting an error: Out of Memory